# JavaFx: Растяжение элементов по вертикали на весь экран

Tags: javafx, button

Задача- растянуть 5 кнопок(button) по вертикали на весь экран. 
Растянуть по горизонтали получается (AnchorPane+VBox).
Но не понятно как того же эффекта добиться по вертикали.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы растянуть по горизонтали, берешь layout HBox, кидаешь туда кнопки, и для каждой кнопки выставляешь Max Height MAX_VALUE ( это в Scene Builder).

Если без него, то делаешь так

```
HBox hBox = new HBox();
Button btn1 = new Button("Btn1");
btn1.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
hBox.getChildren().add(btn1);
```